# How to encode base_64 without slash in PHP?

Tags: php, base64, slash

**Orignal String:**

```
$string = "Home/Gallery/Images/Mountains";
```

**Then I encode this string into base64_encode():**

```
echo base64_encode($string);
```

**Output:**

```
SG9tZS9HYWxsZXJ5L0ltYWdlcy9Nb3VudGFpbnM=
```

**But I want to show this output:**

```
SG9tZS9H/YWxsZXJ5L0lt/YWdlcy9Nb3V/udGFpbnM=
```

↑
Look at the Slashes

means I don't want to that base64_encode() never encode a slash "/" and show slash in orignal form but other string always convert into base64_encode() 
There is someone here who can answer me and please also tell how to decode?

(Sorry for bad english)

Comment: I just gotta ask, why would you not want the slashes encoded?

Comment: @MarkusZeller how to mark as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split it and use the single parts to encode. You can not exclude any chars.

> Note, you will gain some extra padding bytes!

```
$string = "Home/Gallery/Images/Mountains";

echo join('/', array_map(fn($v) => base64_encode($v), explode('/', $string)));
```

> SG9tZQ==/R2FsbGVyeQ==/SW1hZ2Vz/TW91bnRhaW5z

Comment: Hello Markus Zeller, this is wrong answer, i have tried this

Comment: @Burhan, i think its working only in PHP >= 7.4 check: https://3v4l.org/qYBjS

Comment: @Markus Zeller I have php 7.3 and this issue is showing: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')' in D:\Xampp\htdocs\skote\check.php on line 15

Comment: Use this for PHP7.3 `echo join('/', array_map(function ($v) { return base64_encode($v); },
    explode('/', $string))
);
`

Comment: Please tell me the solution of this for php 7.3

Comment: @Burhan I just did. Read my comment above. If you do not use the current version, please specify a version tag.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thanks Thanks Thanks a lot... Second code is working in my laptop

Comment: With PHP7.4 you can use shorthands for lambda functions. Which looks cleaner like you can use in JavaScript.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I have followed you.. Thanks for give me solution